# How to Get string from EditText and insert it to SQLite in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, button, android-edittext

I'm new in Android and I have problem with EditText and SQLite. I want to get string from EditText, and then with a clickable button, insert it to database... but my codes does not work.

This is my code:

```
Button savebtn, clearbtn;
EditText deatxt, numtxt;

public ArrayList<String> num_name, det_name;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    clearbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearbtn);
    savebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savebtn);
    deatxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.deatxt);
    numtxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numtxt);

    clearbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            deatxt.setText("");
            numtxt.setText("");

            savebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Toast.makeText(SarresidActivity.this, "saved!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    DatabaseManager mDatabaseManager = new DatabaseManager(SarresidActivity.this);

                    SQLiteDatabase mainDatabase = mDatabaseManager.getDatabase();

                    String deatxtstring = deatxt.getText().toString();
                    String numtxtstring = numtxt.getText().toString();

                    mainDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO tbl_name(num_name, det_name) VALUES ('" + numtxtstring + "','" + deatxtstring + "');");

                    Cursor mCursor = mainDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_name;", null);

                    num_name = new ArrayList<String>();
                    det_name = new ArrayList<String>();

                    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        // SQL data
                        do {
                            num_name.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("num_name")));
                            det_name.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("det_name")));
                        }
                        while (mCursor.moveToNext());
                    }

                    mCursor.close();

                    mDatabaseManager.closeDatabase();

                }
```

and :

```
 public class DatabaseManager {

public final static String DATABASE_NAME       = "sarresid.db";
public final static String DATABASE_TABLE_NAME = "tbl_name";

private Context            mContext;

private SQLiteDatabase     mSQLiteDatabase;


public DatabaseManager(Context c) {
    mContext = c;

    init();
}


private void init() {
    mSQLiteDatabase = mContext.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

    mSQLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
            + " tbl_name (id INTEGER"
            + ", num_name number"
            + ", det_name VARCHAR"
            + ", PRIMARY KEY(id));");
}


public SQLiteDatabase getDatabase() {
    return mSQLiteDatabase;
}


public void closeDatabase() {
    if (mSQLiteDatabase != null)
        mSQLiteDatabase.close();
}
```

Comment: What does not work? Do you get any errors or does simply nothing happen?

Comment: For some reason you set the OnClickListener of the save button inside of the onclick method of you clear button. 
You should put that directly in the onCreate() method.

Now if you click your save button the "saved" Toast should appear (at least, maybe more?)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried your way of creating and accessing a SQLite database.

The way I normally do it, is by creating a class which extends **[SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html)**

In the **onCreate()** method you can write you create table sql statements like this: 
(The constants are for an easier access later, also they help against spelling mistakes)

```
private static final String TABLE_HOUSE = "house";
private static final String COLUMN_HOUSE_ID = "_id";
private static final String COLUMN_HOUSE_STREET = "street";

[...]

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_HOUSE + " (" 
        + COLUMN_HOUSE_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
        + COLUMN_HOUSE_STREET + " varchar(100))");
}
```

Also you need to create yourself methods to insert or get data.

```
public HouseCursor queryHouse() {
    Cursor wrapped = getReadableDatabase()
        .query(TABLE_HOUSE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    return new HouseCursor(wrapped);
}
```

If you want to i.g. group or order your result you need to replace the appropriate null with the sql code. (Look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for information)

In my example I put the result in a CursorWrapper, which can be put into a CursorAdapter if you want to view the data in a ListView

```
public static class HouseCursor extends CursorWrapper {

    public HouseCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        super(cursor);
    }

    public House getHouse() {
    if (isBeforeFirst() || isAfterLast())
        return null;

        House h = new House();
        h.setId(getLong(getColumnIndex(COLUMN_HOUSE_ID)));
        h.setStreet(getString(getColumnIndex(COLUMN_HOUSE_STREET)));

        return h;
    }
}
```

Data can be inserted this way

```
public long insertHouse(House h) {
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COLUMN_HOUSE_STREET, h.getStreet());

    return getWritableDatabase().insert(TABLE_HOUSE, null, cv);
}
```

The class and the whole app where I took the source code from is [here@github](https://github.com/David-GER/SQLiteDemoApp/blob/master/src/de/frost/david/android/sqlitedemoapp/PlacesDatabaseHelper.java).

Answer (score 0):

even if it tries to insert , what about the id parameter

NOTE : **Primary Key must have a non null and unique value**